# Java Webdriver - Handling a dynamic menu that is sometimes present

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, boolean

In my script there's a dynamic pull down menu that appears depending on the choice made in the previous step.  My code works when the menu is present, but when it's not my script fails.  I'm using the strBusinessType variable to bring in data from my SQL database.

```
//Select Business Type (If Present)
owd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
boolean exists = owd.findElements( By.id("BusinessType1") ).size() !=0;
owd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

if (exists){
    new Select(owd.findElement(By.id("BusinessType1"))).selectByVisibleText(strBusinessType);
}
else{
    System.out.println("Business Type not present");
}
```

Comment: Well how does it fail? Also, set the implicit wait once and once only.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your code in a try block and catch the exception when the element is not present.

```
try {
owd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
boolean exists = owd.findElements( By.id("BusinessType1") ).size() !=0;
owd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

if (exists){
    new Select(owd.findElement(By.id("BusinessType1"))).selectByVisibleText(strBusinessType);
  }
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Business Type not present");
}
```